# How to have a full screen tkinter window displayed properly in different screen sizes

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am creating a tkinter app which is ideally supposed to be opened in different screen sizes (laptops/desktops). I want to manage the widgets using `grid` and `pack` method. And at the end I want to create a `.exe` to open in such computers.

The problem is, even with `grid` management when the program opened in a laptop the app does not properly displayed. How can I solve the issue? I also want to properly display the rectangle and manage the space between widgets.

This can be easily achievable with `.place`, but I read with `.place` we can't create a `.exe` properly displayed on different screen sizes.

Here's a MWE

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkmacosx import Button

class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)
        self.attributes("-topmost", False)
        self.wm_state('zoomed')

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent,bg='#192232') 
        button = Button(self, text="Analysis",command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button.pack()
        
class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent,bg='#192232')
        toolbar1 = tk.Frame(self,bg="#393951")
        toolbar1.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
        
        w = int(parent.winfo_screenwidth())
        h = int(parent.winfo_screenheight())

        label = tk.Label(toolbar1, text="Analysis")
        label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="center")
        
        exit_btn = Button(toolbar1, text="EXIT",command=lambda: app.destroy())
        exit_btn.pack(side="right", padx=5, pady=5)
        
        button1 = Button(toolbar1, text="Home",command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack(side="right", padx=5, pady=5)
        
        frame = tk.Frame(self, bg='#192232')
        frame.pack(side="left", padx=5, pady=5, fill="y")
        
        files_label = tk.Label(frame,text="Spectrum Files",bg='#192232', fg= '#C4BDED',font=16)
        files_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w", pady=5)
        
        scrollbarx = tk.Scrollbar(frame, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
        scrollbarx.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="ew")
        
        listb = tk.Listbox(frame, selectmode = "multiple",height=40,width=40,bd=3,bg='#8c92ac',selectbackground='#6082b6')
        listb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="n")
    
        frame1 = tk.Frame(self, bg='#192232')
        frame1.pack(side="left", pady=32, fill="y")
        
        canvas0 = tk.Canvas(frame1,width=0.623*w,height=0.715*h,background="#192232",highlightthickness=0)
        canvas0.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="w", pady=3)
        canvas0.create_rectangle(5,652,914,5,outline="#8c92ac",fill="#192232",width=2)
        
        canvas3 = tk.Canvas(frame1,width=0.3*w,height=0.5*h,background="#192232",highlightthickness=0)
        canvas3.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        canvas3.create_rectangle(5,206,914,5,outline="#8c92ac",fill="#192232",width=2) 
        canvas3.create_line(15, 20, 207, 20,fill="#8c92ac",width=2) 
        canvas3.create_line(220, 20, 367, 20,fill="#8c92ac",width=2)
          
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Window()             
    app.update()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: There's no limitation to using `place` and creating an exe. However, `place` is arguably the worst way to make a responsive UI.

Comment: It's unclear what you expect the UI to look like. My assumption is that you have some sort of toolbar along the top, a sidebar on the left with some widgets (`frame` and its children) and a workarea on the right (`frame1`) with some other widgets, including a canvas. Is that correct? Is it also correct that you want these two frames to fill the window no matter how big or small the window is?

Comment: @BryanOakley the problem using `place` is when using different screen sizes, the place is not the same. 
for the second question, yes. I have more things to place inside the window, but I am trying to figure out placing these correctly first. As far as I know, I used `grid` and `pack` management, so the window/widgets should keep its aspect ratio when opened from different devices. I also don't want the frames to fill the window, I want to keep the aspect ratio if the app is opened from different devices with different screen sizes

Comment: yes, I know that _can_ be a problem with `place`. However, it gives the ability to use relative positioning and relative sizes, so you can work around that limitation. The key word is "work" - it takes more effort to use `place` to create a responsive UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you want to create a UI that has a toolbar across the top, a sidebar on the left, and a main area on the right. I'm further assuming you want the sidebar and work area to fill the window no matter how big or small the window is.

All three geometry managers (`pack`, `grid`, and `place`) have options to control their behavior. `place` is the most difficult one to use because it requires you to do more of the math. `pack` and `grid` are excellent at creating responsive user interfaces without too much work.

The trick is to divide your UI into groups. Layout the highest level groups first using any tool you want. Then, work your way inward one group at a time. Also, set the default size of the widgets to the absolute minimum acceptable size, and let tkinter grow them to fit the extra space. This is similar to a mobile-first strategy on the web - design for the smallest, and let the framework optimize for larger displays.

I also find it much easier to group all calls to the geometry manager together for all widgets with the same parent. Again, this makes it much easier to visualize the layout when looking at the code.

### The outermost layout

So, we'll start with creating the toolbar, sidebar, and main work area. I'm going to use standard widgets, though custom widgets will work too. With standard widgets it's easy to temporarily use color and/or borders to help visualize the layout.

When creating frames it's important to realize that by default they will grow or shrink to fit all of their children. When starting out they don't have children so it helps to give them a temporary size so that they appear.

Here is how to lay out the toolbar, sidebar, and main work area:

```
import tkinter as tk

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.toolbar = tk.Frame(self, bg="bisque", height=30)
        self.sidepanel = tk.Frame(self, bg="pink")
        self.main = tk.Frame(self, bg="yellow")

        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1, uniform=True)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform=True)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=3, uniform=True

        self.toolbar.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="nsew")
        self.sidepanel.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.main.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

p1 = PageOne(root)
p1.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

Notice that no matter how you change the size of the window, the different areas will maintain their proportional sizes. This is controlled by the `weight` and `uniform` options. `weight` gives a relative proportion, and `uniform` specifies that the final size is relative the proportion.

[image: 640x480 screenshot]

### Filling out each section

With that out of the way, you can now add widgets to each of the sections. In each frame you're free to use either `grid` or `pack`. Just make sure you use the appropriate options to get widgets to fill the frame.

Here's the left panel with the listbox, scrollbar, and label:

```
class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        files_label = tk.Label(self.sidepanel, text="Spectrum Files")
        scrollbarx = tk.Scrollbar(self.sidepanel, orient="horizontal")
        self.listbox = tk.Listbox(self.sidepanel, selectmode="multiple",
                                  yscrollcommand=scrollbarx.set)
        scrollbarx.configure(command=self.listbox.xview)

        # we'll use `pack` here since there's only one widget that
        # needs to grow or shrink to fit.
        files_label.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        scrollbarx.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
        self.listbox.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        ...
```

[image: screenshot with side panel]

You then just continue doing this for the remaining parts of the window.

### Resizing canvas objects

The only difficult part is if you want canvas objects to scale along with the window. The canvas can't automatically redraw canvas items, but it's possible to write code that gets triggered whenever the canvas changes size. We can use that to redraw or resize canvas objects.

For this example, we'll add one canvas to the main area. Your original code has two, but we'll use one to keep the example small. In this example, we want to draw a rectangle that is 90% of the width of the canvas.

Start by adding the canvas to the window, just like we did with the listbox earlier. We'll also draw the rectangle, though the size is irrelevant. It will get reset later.

```
class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        self.canvas0 = tk.Canvas(self.main, bg="lightblue")
        self.canvas0.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        self.canvas0.create_rectangle(10, 10, 20, 20, fill="orange", tags=("rectangle",))
        ...
```

Now, create a function to resize the canvas objects whenever the canvas changes size. We can arrange for the function to be called by binding to the `<Configure>` event. Conveniently, the passed-in `event` object has a `width` and a `height` attribute for the canvas.

```
class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        self.canvas0.bind("<Configure>", self.resize_canvas_objects)
        ...

    def resize_canvas_objects(self, event):
        # we'll make the rectangle 1/2 the height of the canvas, with
        # a 10 pixel border
        canvas = event.widget
        x0, y0 = (10, 10)
        x1, y1 = (event.width-10, event.height//2)
        canvas.coords("rectangle", x0, y0, x1, y1)
        canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
```

We now have a UI where the widgets all resize properly when the main window resizes, and the rectangle inside the canvas also resizes properly when the canvas resizes.

[image: screenshot with canvas]

### EDIT

In a comment you wrote *"I also don't want the frames to fill the window, I want to keep the aspect ratio if the app is opened from different devices with different screen sizes "*. The techniques in this answer can apply to that situation too. For example, you can force widgets to a certain aspect ratio and then add an extra empty row and column to take up any extra space.

The main takeaway here should be to be methodical, and tackle one layout problem at a time. Don't try to get the whole UI done at once. Work in sections, and make sure each section behaves the way you want before moving on.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. So far I've managed to pack the sidepanel and it's children correctly (responsive in different screens), but I am struggling to place a plot inside the main frame. I want to have a rectangle as a border and place a plot inside that. But when the app is opened from a smaller screen the plot is larger than the rectangle. I guess it's because the plot is not resizing correctly. How could I implement that?

Comment: @Chat0924: I have no idea. Tkinter has no native ability to draw plots, so you must be using some other package for that. You'll have to examine the documentation of that package to learn how to scale it.

Comment: I am using matplotlib and `.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH,padx=3, pady=4)` to pack that inside the rectangle